# Filter matched list in Google Sheets QUERY

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a team leaderboard that I am improving. Here are the steps I am trying to streamline:

1. Import table using the **ImportHTML** function

2. Select needed columns using the **Query** function

3. Filter the information in the columns to only include the names that match the names on a specified pre-existing list using the **Filter** function.

4. **Sort** the data by score.

Here is a link to my example workbook: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F0w-7bW8Wbh-eJubyBubeMM_yMzzcSZw28R0OJ-l8q8/edit#gid=1646904068

You can see from the "IS Warm-Up" sheet the former way that this was being done. I am experimenting with streamlining it in "IS-Individual" before streamlining the other sheets as well.
The "Names" sheet contains the team members that I want to pull the results for.

```
   =Sort(
  Filter(
    QUERY(
      IMPORTHTML("https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=getMatchResultsDetail&MatchId=18095&EventId=7&AwardId=1","TABLE",1),
     "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13" & match(Names!A:A,COL1),
Match(Names!A:A,0)),2,True))
```

I've also tried:

```
=Sort(Filter(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=getMatchResultsDetail&MatchId=18095&EventId=7&AwardId=1","TABLE",1),"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13"),Match(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=getMatchResultsDetail&MatchId=18095&EventId=7&AwardId=1","TABLE",1),"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13"),Names!A:A,0)),2,True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=SORT(FILTER(QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=getMatchResultsDetail&MatchId=18095&EventId=7&AwardId=1",
 "TABLE", 1),
 "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13"),
 MATCH(INDIRECT("Names!A1:A"&COUNTA(QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=getMatchResultsDetail&MatchId=18095&EventId=7&AwardId=1",
 "TABLE", 1),
 "SELECT Col1"))+1), 0)), 2, 1)
```

[image]

---

this would work too if the imported table won't change in size:

```
=SORT(FILTER(QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=getMatchResultsDetail&MatchId=18095&EventId=7&AwardId=1",
 "TABLE", 1),
 "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13"),
 MATCH(Names!A1:A89, 0)), 2, 1)
```

Comment: I think this is close, but for some reason, the names that result are not limited to those identified in the "Names" sheet. I tried playing around with it a bit, but couldn't figure out how to correct it. Any ideas?

Comment: its about range mismatch... if you have filter range A1:A10 then parameter needs to be of same size eg: **=filter(A1:A10, B1:B10="x")** if its not then you got error like: **=filter(A1:A10, B1:B9="x")**. in your case output from query has 89 rows (coz importhtml has 89 rows) and you try to filter check it against Names!A:A and that range is equal to 982 rows resulting into error

Comment: I am not getting an official error (#VALUE,#NAME,#N/A) just an unexpected result. The names returned in column AP has 8 of the names listed in the Names sheet, but also includes 32 other names that do not appear in the Names sheet. Unfortunately, the imported table will be changing frequently when the google sheet is in actual usage. Is there a way to check the number of rows that the imported range, append dummy rows and then match against the names?

Comment: appending dummy rows would be like this:

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(FILTER({QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=getMatchResultsDetail&MatchId=18095&EventId=7&AwardId=1",
 "TABLE", 1),
 "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13"); 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♦♠♣♠♣♠♣♠♣♠♣♠♣♠♣♠♣♠♣♠♣♠♣♠♣♠♣♠", 
 ROWS(Names!A1:A)-COUNTA(QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=getMatchResultsDetail&MatchId=18095&EventId=7&AwardId=1",
 "TABLE", 1),
 "SELECT Col1", 0))-1), "♦")), "♠"), "♣", )},
 MATCH(Names!A1:A, 0)), 1, 1, 2, 1))`

Comment: Thanks, @player0 I am still trying to figure this one out. The above suggestions still do not return all of the USAR team members but instead, return non-USAR team members. I've added some additional comments on the sheet to try and make it more clear what I am going for. I appreciate your help though.